# How to assign values to variables in PHP where there are two $s

Tags: php, for-loop

I have variables of the form `$item->value1`, `$item->value2` etc. I want to assign values to these using a for loop like so:

```
for($i=1;$i>20;$i++){
  if($item->value$i == 0)
     $item->value$i=10;
  else
     $item0->value$i=20;
}
```

Rather expected, this doesn't work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take in a `$key` variable & use it like below,

```
for($i=1; $i < 20; $i++){ 
  $key = "value".$i;
  if($item->{$key} == 0)
     $item->{$key}=10;
  else
     $item->{$key}=20;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/QS1kdzKJ)**.

**Note:** I guess you mean by `<` sign & not `>` in your for loop condition. Also use array if you have not specific purpose of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for($i=1;$i>20;$i++){
  $field = "value".$i;
  if($item->$field == 0)
     $item->$field = 10;
  else
     $item0->$field = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$item = array();

for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {

   if ($i == 0) {
   $item[$i] = 20;
   } 
   elseif($item[$i] == 0) {
   $item[$i] = 10;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for($i=1;$i>20;$i++){
  if($item->{"value$i"} == 0)
     $item->{"value$i"}=10;
  else
     $item0->{"value$i"}=20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=1;$i>20;$i++){
  if($item->{value$i} == 0)
     $item->{value$i}=10;
  else
     $item0->{value$i}=20;
}
```

Regards!